# Rails Routing error after deploying to Heroku. While Local runs fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I deployed my rails application to Heroku. It does not run. After I run heroku run rails console I get the follwing erro.

Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_admin_user_session'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:

My routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :business_credit_cards
 resources :createfinancingplans
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
 resources :revenue_lendings
 devise_for :users
 root 'home#index'
 get 'home/financingsituation', as: 'createmyfinancingplan'
 get 'home/financingplan1', as: 'financingplan1'
 get 'home/financingplan2', as: 'financingplan2'
 get 'home/financingplan3', as: 'financingplan3'
 get 'home/financingplan4', as: 'financingplan4'
 get 'home/financingplan5', as: 'financingplan5'
 get 'home/financingplan6', as: 'financingplan6'
 get 'home/financingplan7', as: 'financingplan7'
 get 'home/financingplan8', as: 'financingplan8'
 get 'home/financingplan9', as: 'financingplan9'
 get 'home/financingplan10', as: 'financingplan10'
 get 'home/financingplan11', as: 'financingplan11'
 get 'home/financingplan12', as: 'financingplan12'
 get 'home/financingplan13', as: 'financingplan13'
 get 'home/financingplan14', as: 'financingplan14'
 get 'home/financingplan15', as: 'financingplan15'
 get 'home/financingplan16', as: 'financingplan16'
 get 'home/financingplan17', as: 'financingplan17'
 get 'home/customer', as: 'customer'
 get 'home/businesss', as: 'businesss'
 get 'home/businesscreditrepair', as: 'businesscreditrepair'
 get 'home/shelfcorporations', as: 'shelfcorporations'
 get 'home/businesscreditmonitoring', as: 'businesscreditmonitoring'
 get 'home/sba1', as: 'sba1'
 get 'home/autradeline', as: 'autradeline'
 get 'home/termloan1', as: 'termloan1'
 get 'home/shortterm1', as: 'shortterm1'
 get 'home/personalloans1', as: 'personalloans1'
 get 'home/linesofcredit1', as: 'linesofcredit1'
 get 'home/invoicefactoring1', as: 'invoicefactoring1'
 get 'home/invoicefinancing1', as: 'invoicefinancing1'
 get 'home/equipmentfinancing1', as: 'equipmentfinancing1'
 get 'home/businesscards', as: 'businesscards'
 get 'home/personalcreditcards1', as: 'personalcreditcards1'
 get 'home/merchant', as: 'merchant'
 get 'home/support', as: 'customersupport'
 get 'home/makeextramoney', as: 'makeextramoney'
 get 'home/financing', as: 'financing'
 get 'home/website_creation',as: 'website_creation'
 get 'home/invoice_factoring',as: 'invoice_factoring'
 get 'home/invoice_financing',as: 'invoice_financing'
 get 'home/fax_number',as: 'fax_number'
 get 'home/toll_free_number',as: 'toll_free_number'
 get 'home/virtual_address',as: 'virtual_address'

 resources :users, only: [:edit, :update]
 # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It is casued by line `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` and the `devise_for :users`, the combination creates a new `admin_users_path`.

You should move the line `devise_for :users` to stay above of `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`.

There is a discussion similarly here on [github](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/1632)

Comment: No luck. I moved the devise_for :users above ActiveAdmin.routes(self). The same error, and the link you provided doesn't give any solution. Please help.